# how to find an inverted transformation of a frame

Tags: ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

let's say I have a transformation "map->odom" in the topic /TF as the following example, how do I calculate an inverse transformation of odom -> map,  mathematically speaking. What is the pose of the map frame in the odom frame?

```
 transforms: 
  - 
    header: 
      seq: 0
      stamp: 
        secs: 248
        nsecs: 135000000
      frame_id: "map"
    child_frame_id: "odom"
    transform: 
      translation: 
        x: -0.0035306278666
        y: -0.793366162427
        z: -4.52458409831e-05
      rotation: 
        x: -2.09344237192e-05
        y: 3.72782153808e-06
        z: 0.00294061514174
        w: 0.999995676156
```

thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/356307/how-to-find-an-inverted-transformation-of-a-frame/) by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) on ROS Answers with karma: 125 on 2020-07-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

use an inverse transformation matrix:

[image: image description]

where R is the rotation matrix and P is the translation

https://www.slideshare.net/JoaquimSalvi/lecture-1-rigid-body-transformations

---

Originally posted by [mateusguilherme](https://answers.ros.org/users/39228/mateusguilherme/) with karma: 125 on 2020-07-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0